# Peeking NSPasteboard?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, developer-tools, nspasteboard

Is there some developer tool or other open source app that allows us to peek the current contents of the (or, rather: any) `NSPasteboard` instance?

Browsing through the Xcode directories (contents of the `/Developer` folder before Xcode 4) doesn't turn up anything that looks useful.

We're currently developing the copy and paste feature for our app and some way to conveniently debug what's currently in the pasteboard would be invaluable and would save heaps of development time..

Comment: Did you try `+[[NSPasteboard generalPasteboard] pasteboardItems]`  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple actually has sample code that gives a great start to a project of this type:

[ClipboardViewer at developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/ClipboardViewer/Introduction/Intro.html)

Answer (score 1):

You could always iterate through the pasteboard and log what's there.

```
for(id object in [[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] items]) {
    NSLog(@"Object: %@", object);
}
```

Comment: Sure, I could roll my own - but even logging the description for NSPasteboardItem doesn't give much information (what types it currently contains, etc. - just the class name) so it would be quite some custom code to get any meaningful data (even just the types of the actual data currently stored there)